# FFmpeg on Windows - Background converting

Tags: php, windows, ffmpeg, mp4

I'm having real trouble in getting FFMPEG to convert in the background *Note that when I upload videos and through php the convert works but just sits there and I'm unable to navigate around my website until its finished.

I don't run Linux and don't really have intentions of doing so. And I have windows 7 so unable to use the dev/null/ &. I did try that after reading the very few tutorials online, most of which are outdated due to the depreciated FFmpeg-php and it did absolutely nothing.

The bit of code that I currently have to convert is as follows!

```
    $ffmpeg="C:/FFMPEG/bin/ffmpeg.exe";
    shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i ".$folder.$final_file." ".$destination_mp4." ");
```

so my question would be. What are the right commands to allow a windows user to convert in php within the background successfully, whilst the video converts?

Comment: Question is, are you hosting this on windows? If you're only using windows for development I'd strongly suggest you use a virtual machine as a dev environment / dev server. It help avoid spending (wasting?) time on figuring out/fixing issues on OSes/environments you aren't really going to support anyway. https://box.scotch.io/

Comment: @JimL Currently, yes I will be. I haven't yet used Linux and its something I plan to learn in the future. But for now I'm hoping there is something simple to just fix this small but life changing hiccup. See I'm using wamp also and developing at home to learn about social media building!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this to run scripts in the background without waiting for them to finish:

```
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i ".$folder.$final_file." ".$destination_md4." ";
pclose(popen("start /B $cmd", 'r'));
```

I've also seen this suggested as a way to run background processes in Windows:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$WshShell->Run($cmd, 0, false);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The top lines of code worked like a charm.Now to move onto the loading percentage script.

Comment: For ffmpeg command, it's better: `$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i ".$folder.$final_file." ".$destination_md4."  <nul >nul 2>log.txt";`